# Trim video and extract thumbnail simultaneously

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am using the following two codes for ffmpeg.

Trim Video:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 0 -t 100 -c copy -f mp4 output.mp4
```

Create Thumbnail:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 1 -vframes 1 -f mjpeg output
```

Which works as expected and is super fast, but when I combine the two like so:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 0 -t 100 -c copy -f mp4 output.mp4 -i input.mp4 -ss 1 -vframes 1 -f mjpeg output.jpeg
```

`ffmpeg` runs a re-encoding copy rather than using `-c copy`. I really would like to execute both of these functions in a single `ffmpeg` command.

Below is the output from terminal when it is generating the thumbnail, which is where it appears the re-encoding is happening.

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=  324 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 q=6.3 size=    1792kB time=00:00:12.94 bitrate=1133.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=285 speed=2
frame=  661 fps=660 q=-1.0 q=6.3 size=    4096kB time=00:00:26.43 bitrate=1269.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=622 speed=2
frame= 1013 fps=674 q=-1.0 q=6.3 size=    6912kB time=00:00:40.51 bitrate=1397.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=974 speed= 
frame= 1356 fps=677 q=-1.0 q=6.3 size=    8704kB time=00:00:54.22 bitrate=1314.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=1317 speed=
frame= 1694 fps=677 q=-1.0 q=6.3 size=   11264kB time=00:01:07.75 bitrate=1361.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=1655 speed=
frame= 2031 fps=676 q=-1.0 q=6.3 size=   14080kB time=00:01:21.23 bitrate=1419.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=1992 speed=
frame= 2360 fps=673 q=-1.0 q=6.3 size=   16384kB time=00:01:34.37 bitrate=1422.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=2321 speed=
frame= 2511 fps=672 q=-1.0 Lq=6.3 size=   17695kB time=00:01:40.40 bitrate=1443.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=2474 speed=26.9x    
video:13036kB audio:4684kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: *runs a stream of the copy* --> not clear what this means.

Comment: ok yes i have got it the wrong way round: it runs a re-encoding as opposed to a stream copy. I want the stream copy which is why i used ```-c copy```. It appears that the problem is coming from the thumbnail generation. I have added the output that is generated and edited the question.